# How do I replay the Spark introduction to Disney Infinity?

Tags: disney-infinity

I went through the "Spark" introduction at the beginning of Disney Infinity, but I'd really like to be able to see it again, this time with my son.  Poking through the menus, I don't see any way of doing that.  I've read that it automatically plays the first time you launch the game.  Is there any way to replay the introduction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's one of the places you can access from the Travel menu of the Toy Box menus.  Go to "Prebuilt Toy Box Worlds", then select "Introduction to Disney Infinity".

Note: I believe this level can only be played single player.